# Is it possible to have a strongly typed class for Repository Pattern?

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a repository pattern, however I don't understand how its possible when entities have id's of different types. Currently I have to fallback to using object, while I would really like to use the specific type of the id of the entity the repository is holding.

```
interface IEntity
{
    object GetId();
}

class Foo : IEntity
{
    private string id;

    public Foo(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public object GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

class Bar : IEntity
{
    private int id;

    public Bar(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public object GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

class Repository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private Dictionary<object, T> entities = new Dictionary<object, T>();

    public IEnumerable<T> List => entities.Values.AsEnumerable();

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        entities.Add(entity.GetId(), entity);
    }

    public T Get(object id)
    {
        return entities[id];
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo("0");

        var bar = new Bar(0);

        var fooRepo = new Repository<Foo>();
        fooRepo.Add(foo);
        fooRepo.Get(foo.GetId());

        var barRepo = new Repository<Bar>();
        barRepo.Add(bar);
        barRepo.Get(bar.GetId());
    }
}
```

I also tried something like:

```
class Repository<Id, Value> where Value : IEntity
{
    private Dictionary<Id, Value> entities = new Dictionary<Id, Value>();

    public IEnumerable<Value> List => entities.Values.AsEnumerable();

    public void Add(Value entity) // But got stuck here, I don't want to pass in Id as separate parameter, I want it auto magically from the interface.
    {
        entities.Add(entity.GetId(), entity);
    }

    public Value Get(Id id)
    {
        return entities[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: First off it's not a `Repository pattern` it is a generic repository and some developers consider it more [like an anti-pattern](https://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/) than something useful, mainly because we have abstractions over abstractions...  You could make your `IEntity` interface generic and then do: `class Repository<Id, Value> where Value : IEntity<Id>`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a generic type of the key to `IEntity`. E.g.,

```cs
interface IEntity<TId>
{
    TId GetId();
}

class Foo : IEntity<string>
{
    private string id;

    public Foo(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public string GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

class Repository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : IEntity<TId>
{
    private Dictionary<TId, TEntity> entities = new Dictionary<TId, TEntity>();

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        entities.Add(entity.GetId(), entity);
    }

    public TEntity Get(TId id)
    {
        return entities[id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joel's solution could be extended to allow for variance. The same way generic collections implement both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

Entity

```
interface IEntity
{
    object GetId();
}

interface IEntity<TId> : IEntity
{
    new TId GetId();
}

abstract class EntityBase<TId> : IEntity<TId>
{
    protected TId id;

    protected EntityBase(TId id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TId GetId() => id;

    object IEntity.GetId() => GetId();
}
```

Repository

```
abstract class Repository
{
    protected Dictionary<object, IEntity> entities;

    protected Repository()
    {
        entities = new Dictionary<object, IEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(IEntity entity) 
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        entities.Add(entity.GetId(), entity);
    }

    public virtual IEntity Get(object id)
    {
        if (id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
        return entities[id];
    }
}

abstract class Repository<TId, TEntity> : Repository 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{
    protected Repository() : base() { }

    public override void Add(IEntity entity)
    {
        Add((TEntity)entity);
    }

    public override IEntity Get(object id)
    {
        return Get((TId)id);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        entities.Add(entity.GetId(), entity);
    }

    public TEntity Get(TId id)
    {
        if (id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
        return (TEntity)entities[id];
    }
}
```

Use Case

```
class Foo : EntityBase<string>
{
    public Foo(string id) : base(id) { }
}

class Bar : EntityBase<int>
{
    public Bar(int id) : base(id) { }
}

class FooRepository : Repository<string, Foo>
{
    public FooRepository() { }
}

class BarRepository : Repository<int, Bar>
{
    public BarRepository() { }
}
```

Test

```
[TestMethod]
public void IEntitySupport()
{
    // use IEntity and object
    IEntity bar = new Bar(1);
    Repository barRepository = new BarRepository();
    barRepository.Add(bar);
    var bar2 = barRepository.Get((object)1);
    Assert.AreSame(bar, bar2);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TEntitySupport()
{
    // use TEntity and TId
    var foo = new Foo("a");
    var fooRepository = new FooRepository();
    fooRepository.Add(foo);
    var foo2 = fooRepository.Get("a");
    Assert.AreSame(foo, foo2);
}
```